# iOS: Split up Key - Value joined by Equal sign from NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, split

I have following string;

```
    key = value = 123
```

I want to split up this string into two strings `"key"` and `"value = 123"`. What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking of using `componentsSeparatedByString` by "=" and then combine last two components but for me, `"key ="` is fixed but right side it can be any value like `"value1 = 123, value2 = 123"` so I can't use this approach.

Basically if there is a good way to get `key` (all characters before first = sign) and after first = sign whatever remained is the `value` then it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NSScanner!

```
       NSString *key, *value;
       NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourstring];
       [scanner scanUpToString:@"=" intoString:&key];
       [scanner scanString:@"=" intoString:nil];
       value = [yourstring substringFromIndex:scanner.scanLocation];

       key = [key stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
       value = [value stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

String `"key = value1 = 123, value2 = 456"` would result in `key = "key"` and `value = "value1 = 123, value2 = 456".`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question? The following code will fetch the key, regardless of what it is and then strip that from the original string to get the value.

```
NSString *strKeyKalue = @"key = value = 123";
NSArray *aryKeyValue = [strKeyKalue componentsSeparatedByString:@" = "];
NSString *key = [aryKeyValue objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *values = [strKeyValue substringFromIndex:[key length] + 3]; // Remember ' = '
```

So `max_int = 17477575` would result in `key = max_int` and `value = 17477575`

Comment: This will fail if there are no spaces around equal to sign!

Comment: It will - consistency costs nothing :)

Comment: right :) but you should't assume anything especially hard coding stuffs while writing code :-) anything bad happens!

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is pretty confusing.
If you want to separate just the key from value = 123, use commentsSeperatedByString and then
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat"@"%@ = %@", string1, string2];